Binary Search Tree remove node, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt
I'm currently working on the odin project on Binary Search Tree. I'm trying to make deleteNode work, and I'm working on removing a node if it is a leaf node.
Here's my code:

class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }
  buildTree(array) {
    //accepts an array of integers and sort them into binary search tree;
    //loop through the given array, creating a node for each item. insert nodes into the array in a binarySearchTree  manner.
    array.forEach((item) => {
      this.insert(item);
    });
  }
  insert(value) {
    //accepts an integer value and sort it into the tree;
    let newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.root === null) {
      this.root = newNode;
      return this;
    }
    let current = this.root;
    while (true) {
      if (value === current.value) return undefined;
      if (value < current.value) {
        if (current.left === null) {
          current.left = newNode;
          return this;
        }
        current = current.left;
      } else if (value > current.value) {
        if (current.right === null) {
          current.right = newNode;
          return this;
        }
        current = current.right;
      }
    }
  }

 deleteNode(value) {
    let current = this.root;
    let prev;
    if (!current) {
      console.log("hello");
      return undefined;
    }
    while (current) {
      if (current.value > value) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.left;
      } else if (current.value < value) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.right;
      } else {
        //node found.
        //case 1: node is leaf node, no left and right children
        if (!current.left && !current.right) {
          if (prev.value > current.value) {
            prev.left = null;
          } else {
            prev.right = null;
          }

          console.log("leaf node deleted", current);
          return this;
        }
        //case 2: node has either left or right child
        //case 3: node has both left and right children
      }
    }
  }
  find(value) {
    //accepts an integer value and search for it in the tree. IF found ,return the node with the value;
    if (this.root === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    let current = this.root;
    while (current) {
      if (current.value === value) {
        return current;
      } else if (current.value > value) {
        current = current.left;
      } else {
        current = current.right;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  levelOrder(callback) {
    //BFS
    const queue = [];
    const data = [];
    let node = this.root;
    queue.push(this.root);
    while (queue.length) {
      node = queue.shift();
      data.push(node.value);
      if (node.left) queue.push(node.left);
      if (node.right) queue.push(node.right);
    }
    return data;
  }

  inOrder(callback) {
    //inOrderDFS
    if (this.root === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const data = [];
    let current = this.root;
    const traverse = (node) => {
      if (node.left) {
        traverse(node.left);
      }
      data.push(node.value);
      if (node.right) {
        traverse(node.right);
      }
    };
    traverse(current);
    return data;
  }
  preOrder(callback) {
    //preOrderDFS
    if (this.root === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const data = [];
    let current = this.root;
    const traverse = (node) => {
      data.push(node.value);
      if (node.left) traverse(node.left);
      if (node.right) traverse(node.right);
    };
    traverse(current);
    return data;
  }

  postOrder(callback) {
    //postOrderDFS
    if (this.root === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const data = [];
    let current = this.root;
    const traverse = (node) => {
      if (node.left) traverse(node.left);
      if (node.right) traverse(node.right);
      data.push(node.value);
    };
    traverse(current);
    return data;
  }
}

const odinTree = new BinarySearchTree();
const array = [10, 20, 12, 15, 11, 50, 35, 21, 5, 2, 9, 3];
odinTree.buildTree(array);


Here's the code for deleteNode:
 deleteNode(value) {
    let current = this.root;
    let prev;
    if (!current) {
      console.log("hello");
      return undefined;
    }
    while (current) {
      if (current.value > value) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.left;
      } else if (current.value < value) {
        prev = current;
        current = current.right;
      } else {
        //node found.
        //case 1: node is leaf node, no left and right children
        if (!current.left && !current.right) {
          if (prev.value > current.value) {
            prev.left = null;
          } else {
            prev.right = null;
          }

          console.log("leaf node deleted", current);
          return this;
        }
        //case 2: node has either left or right child
        //case 3: node has both left and right children
      }
    }
  }

I tried running the code on console, and it actually worked. However, I tried refreshing the page and I pressed keyup to run the same code to delete the same leaf node and it got stuck.
I'm quite sure my code is fine because i tried typing out tree.deleteNode on several leaf nodes and they all worked. The page only got stuck whenever i tried running deleteNode by pressing keyup.
Any inputs would be appreciated, thank you!

Can you share the steps to reproduce the issue? Like the specific things needed to enter into the console to cause the infinite loop?

hi nick, so i tried making a new tree in vsc with this.

Please click [edit] then the button marked [<>] and make a runnable [mcve]

const odinTree = new BinarySearchTree();
const array = [10, 20, 12, 15, 11, 50, 35, 21, 5, 2, 9, 3];
odinTree.buildTree(array);
then i typed out manually: odinTree.deleteNode(21) which is a leaf node, and it worked. Next, i pressed keyup just so i dont have to type out the whole thing again, and i changed 21 to 35(which is now leaf node), then it got stuck.. what's weirder is that IF i manually typed odinTree.deleteNode(21) and then manually typed odinTree.deleteNode(35), it worked, and i can keep going with the other leaves. the chrome tab only got stuck if i pressed keyup to run the same

i'll edit my code with the new Tree variable, just a sec

hey guys, i think i found where it went wrong.. when i pressed keyup after deleting a leaf, the code tried running deleting the deleted node in the background and got stuck.. i havent actually completed the code, i think that's why it went in an infinite loop.. sorry for the confusion.. Edit: yep found it.. i added 'return false' outside after the while loop and it's working now.. sorry guys

Feel free to delete the question
